# View and order by

Tags: oracle, view, subquery, sql-order-by

Why can't a subquery of a view have an order by clause? Similarly why one can't change/delete a row through a view when:

1. Group by is used in view
2. Distinct is used in view

Comment: You should accept some of the answers people have given you to give them credit.

Comment: Why would you need to order a sub query?

Comment: Actually "similarly" is wrong.  These are are two distinct questions and should be asked as such.  ORDER BY is not allowed in *any* sub-query, not just in a sub-query in a view.  Whereas your second question applies just to views with aggregating functions.  SO is not a forum, it is a Q&A site.  Consequently the organization and categorization of questions is important.

Answer (score 2):

ORDER BY generally orders the result set (i.e. columns after first select before FROM), never the subqueries.
Subqueries are used to qualify, not to order results.

Comment: Similarly why one cant change/delete a row through a view when
1)group by is used in view
2)distnct is used in view